# how to disable RectButton from react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: react-native, button, react-native-gesture-handler

title is pretty much the question.  On react-native buttons ie touchableOpacity you have the disabled prop but it doesn't appear to work on RectButton

```
<RectButton onPress={onPress} disabled={isDisabled}></RectButton>
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a prop **"enabled"** use that.

```
<RectButton onPress={onPress} enabled={!isDisabled}></RectButton>
```